# On django admin why is django adding ?_changelist_filters to url?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Why django adds on url `?_changelist_filters=user%3D5275` when I click on add? My url on change_list was `?user=5275` initially.
The issue is that the user should be selected in the select input and it isn't. If i change it in `?user=5275` is working.

How can I make django to 'read'`?_changelist_filters=user%3D5275` or to change it in `?user=5275`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add in AdminForm something like this:

```
class UsersAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    @staticmethod
    def parse_filter_kwargs(**kwargs):
        if 'initial' in kwargs:
            if u'_changelist_filters' in kwargs['initial']:
                filters = kwargs['initial'][u'_changelist_filters']
                var, value = filters.split('=')
                if var == u'user':
                    return {'initial': {var: value}}
        return kwargs

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs = self.parse_filter_kwargs(**kwargs)
        super(UsersAdminForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1):

solution for all `_changelist_filters` params

```
class ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
    @staticmethod
    def parse_filter_kwargs(**kwargs):
        if 'initial' in kwargs:
            if u'_changelist_filters' in kwargs['initial']:
                filters = kwargs['initial'].pop('_changelist_filters')
                for key, value in [p.split('=') for p in filters.split('&')]:
                    kwargs['initial'][key] = value
        return kwargs

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs = self.parse_filter_kwargs(**kwargs)
        super(ProductForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from urllib.parse import parse_qsl

query_params = dict(parse_qsl(request.GET['_changelist_filters']))

print(query_params.get('user'))
```